# sql query doesn't update JTable

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jtable

I am currently making an app that allows customers to make accounts and for managers to sign up staff (among other things).

I can get the JTable to display all the accounts but when I click on a button to add a staff member I have to exit the frame and then go back into it to see the update, but I want it to update on the spot.

The next three bits of code are in the DbConnect class and the final one is in the ManageAccount class.

```
 //This gets the data and creates the tablemodel
 public static DefaultTableModel buildTableModel(ResultSet rs)
        throws SQLException {

    ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();

    // names of columns
    Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();
    int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
    for (int column = 1; column <= columnCount; column++) {
        columnNames.add(metaData.getColumnName(column));
    }

    // data of the table
    Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();
    while (rs.next()) {
        Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<Object>();
        for (int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= columnCount; columnIndex++) {
            vector.add(rs.getObject(columnIndex));
        }
        data.add(vector);
    }

    return new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);

}
```

This is the query I use to display the accounts in the JTable

```
 public JTable ManageAcc2(JTable t) {
    try {
        String query = ("SELECT * FROM staff");
        rt = st.executeQuery(query);

        t = new JTable(buildTableModel(rt));

} catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }

 return t;
}
```

This is the query that adds an extra staff member

```
public void AddStaff(JTable t) {

    try {

        String query = "INSERT INTO staff VALUES('" + NULL + "','" + NULL + "','" + NULL + "','" + NULL + "','" + NULL + "','staff')";
        st.executeUpdate(query);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

Finally this is a separate class where I create the table that contains all the data

```
public class ManageAccount extends JPanel{

JPanel jNorth = new JPanel();
JPanel jCenter = new JPanel();
JPanel jSouth = new JPanel();
    JTable t = new JTable();

JScrollPane listScroll = new JScrollPane();
    JScrollPane listScroll2 = new JScrollPane();
    JScrollPane listScroll3 = new JScrollPane();
    JButton AddStaff = new JButton("Add Staff");
JButton goBack = new JButton("Back");
    ManagerDashboard md;
    DbConnect dbc = new DbConnect();  

ManageAccount(ManagerDashboard m){
      try{  


            this.md = m;
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 400));
    this.setVisible(true);

    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.add(jNorth, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    this.add(jCenter, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.add(jSouth, BorderLayout.SOUTH);                       

            listScroll = new JScrollPane(dbc.ManageAcc(t));
            listScroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 116));

            listScroll2 = new JScrollPane(dbc.ManageAcc2(t));
            listScroll2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 116));

    jNorth.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    jNorth.add(goBack, BorderLayout.WEST);
    goBack.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

     md.removeManageAccount();

        }
    }); 

            jCenter.add(listScroll);  
            jCenter.add(listScroll2);

            jSouth.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    jSouth.add(AddStaff, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            AddStaff.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                dbc.AddStaff(t);

                }
            });          
            }catch(Exception ex){
             System.out.println(ex);
}      
}

}
```

I have looked at other answers to similar questions but using methods like setModel(), repaint(),etc doesn't seem to work for me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Once you've created your first instance of JTable, simply update it's TableModel

Comment: I removed the JTable from the ManageAccount class and just put it in the DbConnect while making AddStaff return a JTable and it worked!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the jTable reference the ManageAccount class' field rather than local variable.

In your `AddStaff` you pass the JTable but use the introduced field instead. After inserting call something like this

```
    String query = ("SELECT * FROM staff");
    rt = st.executeQuery(query);

    theTableField.setModel(buildTableModel(rt));
```